# Pass an object/structure to a UITableViewCell, or configure the cell in configureCell:atIndexPath:?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, design-patterns, uitableview

I need to configure a custom table view cell with the contents of a model object. Which is the preferred design pattern? I'm not looking for the "right" answer, just a good discussion of the pros and cons.

1) Manually configure the cell in configureCell:atIndexPath:?

```
- configureCell:atIndexPath:
    {
    myCell.field1 = modelObject.field1 ;
    myCell.field2 = modelObject.field2 ;
    }
```

2) Just code the custom cell to accept the model object and pass the model object wholesale to the cell in configureCell:atIndexPath:?

```
- configureCell:atIndexPath:
    {
    myCell.model = modelObject ;
    }
```

According to the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), perhaps (1) is better. However, when the cell needs to handle user actions, is a tableview a more appropriate controller, or the cell itself (use the cell as a [ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel))? I think definitely the latter may make for clearer code:

1) Behaviors with table view as controller

```
// tableview
- configureCell:atIndexPath:
    {
    myCell.field1 = model.field1 ;
    myCell.button.delegate = myDelegate ; // have to define MyDelegate protocol
    }

// Call behavior in cell
[self.button.delegate delegateCall] ;

// delegate
- (void) delegateCall
    {
    // find out which cell was manipulated
    // find the object associated with the table cell
    [theFoundModelObject myBehavior] ;
    }
```

2) Behavior with the cell as a ViewModel:

```
- configureCell:atIndexPath:
    {
    myCell.model = modelObject ; // cell has direct access to model behavior
    }

// Call behavior in cell
[self.model myBehavior] ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a fan of a certain form of #2.

I don't think the controller should have to setup everything in the cell, but I also don't think the cell should hold onto a model longer than it has too. So my cell subclasses have a method in the form of:

```
- (void)updateCellWithModel:(YourModel *)model;
```

That function does not hold a reference to the model, but uses the properties of the model to update the cell's state. I prefer to make all my models CoreData backed, and so NSFetchedResultsController's provides the hooks to properly update the cell again.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the approach of creating a custom cell subclass and passing it the whole model object to configure itself with.

It's maximally flexible if you later decide that the cell needs to use extra fields from the model and leaves you free to change the cell's visual layout and the model's internal structure without having to also update your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the answer, still here is my thought. I would go with option1. Why because the UITableViewCell is a View and for the sake of reusability I would not pass it an object. I would not couple model with View. I would rather prefer to use it in cellForRowAtIndexPath. This is my thought